# Display a Pandas column as percentage

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have downloaded the attribute 'grossMargins' with yfinance into a Pandas dataframe, the column has the format 0.3646. Internally it should be used to calculate further, but it should be displayed as 36.46%. How can I make this happen?

Here is a little example of a code:

```
import yfinance as yf

# Define the ticker symbol of the company
ticker = "AAPL"

# Download the financial data
company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
financials = company.financials

# Get the gross margins
gross_margins = financials['Gross Margins']

# Save the gross margins to a CSV file
gross_margins.to_csv('gross_margins.csv', header=True)

# Display the gross margins
print(gross_margins)
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only dealing with the one column (gross margins) or don't mind the same formatting being applied to all float values, the code below should work. If you need to format just a single column in your dataframe, you may need to convert the values to a string (making further calculations break, since you mentioned this is a requirement). An option for this latter case would be to simply make a copy of the dataframe, format that copy for display, but keep the  original for calculations. I couldn't get the `df.style.format()` methods mentioned in similar questions to work, possibly due to Pandas version.

```
import pandas as pd
# pd version == 2.0.1

margin_data = {"margins":[0.3646, 0.2584, 0.8954]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(margin_data)

# What you were printing before
print("Old formatting")
gross_margins = my_df['margins']
print(gross_margins)

# Apply new formatting to all floats
print("\nNew formatting")
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2%}'.format
gross_margins = my_df['margins']
print(gross_margins)

# Confirm values are still what you expect
print("\nValues")
print(my_df['margins'].iloc[0])

# Apply formatting to only one column, but makes 
# values a string instead of float
print("\nString formatting single column")
margin_data["more data"] = [1,2,3]
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(margin_data)
my_df2['margins'].map('{:.2%}'.format)
print(my_df2)
```

Produces:

```
Old formatting
0    0.3646
1    0.2584
2    0.8954
Name: margins, dtype: float64

New formatting
0   36.46%
1   25.84%
2   89.54%
Name: margins, dtype: float64

Values
0.3646

String formatting single column
   margins  more data
0   36.46%          1
1   25.84%          2
2   89.54%          3
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to set the display options for **all** floats to be in the %format (and then have to change back sometime). You could use a context manager: `with pd.option_context("display.float_format", '{:.2%}'.format):` then have the assignment and print statements indented below. The option is automatically revoked on leaving the code block.

Comment: I didn't know about that feature, good catch!